# html5 video wont play ANY mp4 encodes on ipad

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video, ffmpeg

Im trying to embed a mp4 on a page with the HTML5 video tag. Everything works fine on Desktop but nothing will work on an iPad Version 9.3.4. 
I have the mime types in an .htaccess file. I've tried various encodes with handbrake, Miro and FFmpeg conversions.

Even sample videos like at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and [videojs](http://videojs.com/) don't play. 
The video will play if i actually sync it to the iPad, but nothing works over the web. An older iPad actually plays mp4s through the HTML5 video player. 
I'm ready to throw this POS iPad through a window.

```
 <video autoplay="false" width="320" height="240" controls="true" id='video'>
  <source src="http://webnamehere.com/video/bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>

Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

Has anyone found a way to fix this? Is there ANY encoding that this thing will actually play? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: given that a lot of people successfully play mp4 video in html5 pages on iPad I don't think that's to blame. How about you should a real sample that's failing so we can help? Also, `autoplay` and `controls` are not true/false, they are simple present or not, and your sample does not include a closing `</video>` tag which may be oversight or the problem. Are you playing in Safari, Chrome or what browser?

Answer (score 0):

The mp4 might need the correct Profile to play on that device.

If you convert with ffmpeg, try adding

```
-profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -movflags +faststart
```

See here the different profile levels.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Compatibility

Here is a full command:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -y -vcodec libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -qcomp 0.8 -preset medium -acodec aac -b:a 400k -x264-params ref=4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -movflags +faststart "video.mp4"
```